# Failed to run WPF installation file created by Visual Studio Installer Project

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

The WPF application failed to run after installing the .msi file created by the **Visual Studio Installer Project** even though it worked on the primary project. Then I noticed that some of the DLLs had red lines. Is this related to this issue?

Can you please let me know how I can fix this error?

Here is my dev environment.

- .NET Framework 4.8
- Visual Studio 2022

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found prerequisites are different from the primary project version. .NET Framework 4.7 was checked by default, so I unchecked it and checked .NET Framework 4.8. The above errors are gone. Failed to run WPF installation file using Visual Studio Installer Project